# Save state of the fragment backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack

What is the best way to save the state of the fragment backstack? Im having a problem when I open my application from the recent list, the order of the fragments is not the same as when I closed the application.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(NameYourFragment)` you can't put the fragment in the backstack. When you want delete this fragment to the backstack you can use `fragmentTransaction.popBackstack()`. This methods and add, replace should be enough.

Hope it helps you.